# Are there advantageous situations when we cascade filters by descending Q-factor instead of ascending?

Tags: filter, active-filter, passive-filter, high-pass-filter, digital-filter

We usually cascade filters in ascending Q-factor to avoid saturation in each individual stage. But are there advantageous situations when we cascade filters by descending Q-factor?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I made the mistake once of getting this wrong and it was a tad embarrassing.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no risk of saturation you might want a relatively broadband preamplifier before you apply a higher-Q filter. The input-referred noise of a high-Q active filter can be pretty bad.

Comment: aren't you just agreeing with the original statement rather than examining reasons why the reverse might also be applicable in certain situations?

Comment: @Andyaka I don't see the word "noise" in the original statement.